# StructureMap Error: No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, structuremap

very new to Structure-Map. trying to figure it out how it works and how can i benefit from it.

i have got this so far..

**Global.asax.cs:**

```
IContainer container = new Container(x =>
    {
         x.For<IControllerActivator>().Use
              <StructureMapControllerActivator>();
         x.For<IUserRepo>().Use<UserRepo>();
    }); 

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
```

**StructureMapControllerActivator:**

```
public class StructureMapControllerActivator : IControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public StructureMapControllerActivator(IContainer container )
    {
        this._container = container;
    }

    public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return _container.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;
    }
}
```

**StructreMapDependencyResolver:**

```
private readonly IContainer _container;

    public StructureMapDependencyResolver(IContainer container )
    {
        this._container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        object instance = _container.TryGetInstance(serviceType);
        if(instance == null && !serviceType.IsAbstract)
        {
            _container.Configure(c => c.AddType(serviceType,serviceType));
            instance = _container.TryGetInstance(serviceType);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _container.GetAllInstances(serviceType).Cast<object>();
    }
}
```

**My AccountController:**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserRepo _userRepo;

    private AccountController()
    {
        _userRepo = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUserRepo>();
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Error Code & Description:**

> StructureMap Exception Code:  202
>   No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily MBP_Blog.Controllers.AccountController
>   MBP-Blog, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

I have a Interface Name : IUserRepo and a repository Name: UserRepo

please help as I try to google but dint find any solution within first 3 pages.

**New error after using @Martin's code:**

> StructureMap Exception Code:  180
>   StructureMap cannot construct objects of Class MBP_Blog.Controllers.AccountController, MBP-Blog, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null because there is no public constructor found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the `StructureMapControllerActivator`, I don't think you need it.  If you keep it, you need to add a mapping for your `AccountController`.

Also, use Controller Injection instead, it will make unit testing easier:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserRepo _userRepo;

    public AccountController(IUserRepo userRepo)
    {
        _userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Also again, for your Container, you can default the mappings.  This will automatically map `IService` to `Service` :

```
IContainer container = new Container(
            x =>
                {
                    x.Scan(scan =>
                               {
                                   scan.Assembly("MBP_Blog");
                                   scan.Assembly("MBP_Blog.Data");
                                   scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                               });
                });
```

Comment: @martin.. thanks for your answer..i tried using your method..but still i am getting the error. please look at the updated error..

Comment: thanks...somehow i got it working ...i dont know whether its a best practice tthanks for your help..o use it or not..will ask another question on that ...

Comment: I believe it should called as "Constructor Injection" instead of "Controller Injection"